# Digitalclock runtime error when trying to change font

Tags: java, android, xml, runtime-error

I'm trying to display a digitalclock in the activity, but when I add the code to change the font, the app crashes:

Note: the font is in the asset folder and the name is correct.

```
package asd.asasdx;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.DigitalClock;

public class ClockzActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        DigitalClock digitalClock = (DigitalClock) findViewById(R.id.digitalClock);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Typeface type = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "DS_DIGI.TTF");
        digitalClock.setTypeface(type);
    }
}
```

And XML:

```
<DigitalClock
    android:id="@+id/digitalClock"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:text="DigitalClock"
    android:textSize="70dp"
    android:textColor="#00FF00"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:shadowColor="#00FF00"
    android:shadowRadius="16" />
```

But when I run the app, it crashes because of a runtime error:

```
03-26 19:05:49.242: E/AndroidRuntime(29310): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-26 19:05:49.242: E/AndroidRuntime(29310): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{asd.asasdx/asd.asasdx.ClockzActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made
03-26 19:05:49.242: E/AndroidRuntime(29310):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
03-26 19:05:49.242: E/AndroidRuntime(29310):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
03-26 19:05:49.242: E/AndroidRuntime(29310):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
03-26 19:05:49.242: E/AndroidRuntime(29310):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
03-26 19:05:49.242: E/AndroidRuntime(29310):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-26 19:05:49.242: E/AndroidRuntime(29310):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-26 19:05:49.242: E/AndroidRuntime(29310):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
03-26 19:05:49.242: E/AndroidRuntime(29310):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-26 19:05:49.242: E/AndroidRuntime(29310):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-26 19:05:49.242: E/AndroidRuntime(29310):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-26 19:05:49.242: E/AndroidRuntime(29310):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
03-26 19:05:49.242: E/AndroidRuntime(29310):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-26 19:05:49.242: E/AndroidRuntime(29310): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made
03-26 19:05:49.242: E/AndroidRuntime(29310):    at android.graphics.Typeface.<init>(Typeface.java:147)
03-26 19:05:49.242: E/AndroidRuntime(29310):    at android.graphics.Typeface.createFromAsset(Typeface.java:121)
03-26 19:05:49.242: E/AndroidRuntime(29310):    at asd.asasdx.ClockzActivity.onCreate(ClockzActivity.java:15)
03-26 19:05:49.242: E/AndroidRuntime(29310):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
03-26 19:05:49.242: E/AndroidRuntime(29310):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
03-26 19:05:49.242: E/AndroidRuntime(29310):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
03-26 19:05:49.242: E/AndroidRuntime(29310):    ... 11 more
```

What's the problem?

Comment: move this line `setContentView(R.layout.main);` after `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`

Comment: are u sure your font is in assets folder?

Comment: I can't post an image because of the reputation but yes, it's in the assets folder

Comment: if you have font in assets/fonts/DS_DIGI.TTF then use `Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/DS_DIGI.TTF");`

Comment: but it's in assets/DS_DIGI.TTF

Comment: sorry hoconosc, plz check font name?

Comment: bez this error occur only when you have any font related problem your code is perfect

Comment: as noted in the question: Note: the font is in the asset folder and the name is correct.

Comment: you're right man, it's a problem of the font. answer the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code is right but this error occur only if we have any fonts related problem so check your font location and font name may be possible not same or any other problem in font.